# Encrypting Analytics Data in MongoDB

Tags: xdb, security

Does Sitecore support any options for encrypting analytics data stored in MongoDB?

One of our clients wants to store personal information in xDB, but has required that we verify that the data can be stored encrypted while at rest. I took a brief look online and through the decompiled source and I don't see any way to configure this, natively. I'm not sure if Sitecore currently supports encrypting data in MongoDB, but if anyone has found a way to do so then that is what I'm looking for.

For clarification, I am aware that MongoDB supports SSL for encrypting the communication of data. Specifically, I am looking for a way to encrypt that data while at rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Sitecore MongoDB compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/633863), if you are using Sitecore 8.2 and you are using Mongo 3.2.1 Enterprise with data-at-rest encryption (Wired Tiger only), it should be supported by default.

[image]

If you are still using the MMAPv1 database engine with Mongo, you can [read this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/) guide for the steps to convert a database from MMAPv1 to WiredShark.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply encrypt the data in custom facets on the application layer just before saving in to the MongoDB.

As for the standard facets and contact details, Sitecore do not have such functionality out of the box.

Please have a look on below article about security encryption at rest.

Storage Encryption: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/security-encryption-at-rest/#storage-encryption